# python 2d list get the sorted array based on closest value

Tags: python, list

I have 2d array like this

```
arry = [[6,5,7,8],[2,5,5,6]]
```

The first two values are x,y are points in graph.
I want the sorted array based on the points i give for search. So, if i give [3,5] Since this is close to [2,5] i need to get [[2,5,5,6],[6,5,7,8]]

Thanks in advance !

Another example

```
[[6, 6, 8, 10],  [3, 3, 8, 10], [15, 15, 8, 10]]
```

If i give [16,16], we should get

```
[[15, 15, 8, 10], [6, 6, 8, 10],  [3, 3, 8, 10]]
```

Comment: @tech_tutorial could you explain better what you are trying to achieve? Is `[2,5,5,6]` the list of x coordinates and `[6,5,7,8]` the list of y's?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question? Reading this it makes me think arry[0] is your x values and arry[1] is the y values, but you say the closest index to 3,5 is 2,5,5,6? I was thinking the output would be the index of the closest coordinates, so answer = [item[0] for item in arry]. Please clarify!

Comment: Are you using `arrays` (like `numpy.ndarray`) or python `lists`? What do you mean by 'nearest'? Euclidean distance?

Comment: I have updated the question.  I just want to search with first two values.

Comment: its just python list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you want to sort your sublist based on the minimum difference from a reference list.

You could use `sorted` and its `key` parameter.

If you need to take the minimum difference in order of the points:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda e: [abs(a-b) for a,b in zip(e, [2,5])])
```

output: `[[2, 5, 5, 6], [6, 5, 7, 8]]`

If you want the **euclidean** distance (makes more sense from a geometrical perspective as this is the length of a straight line between the points), you need to take the sum of the square difference:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda e: sum((a-b)**2 for a,b in zip(e, [2,5])))
```

output: `[[2, 5, 5, 6], [6, 5, 7, 8]]`

*NB. I am not computing the square root here are the squares and their roots are ordered the same*

*NB2. if you want to make thinks multi-dimensional, just add more value in `zip`, for example: `zip(e, [2,5,4])`*

Comment: @techtutorial so which one do you need?

Comment: Thank so much for the answer !! But I am getting [[3, 3, 8, 10], [6, 6, 8, 10], [15, 15, 8, 10]] with both solution l = [[6, 6, 8, 10], [3, 3, 8, 10], [15, 15, 8, 10]] ans = sorted(l, key=lambda e: [a-b for a,b in zip(e, [16,16])]) But this should give [[15, 15, 8, 10], [6, 6, 8, 10], [3, 3, 8, 10]]

Comment: How is [2,5] closer to [15,15] than [3,3]?? Please update your question to add those examples and provide the breakdown of the calculation to explain how [15,15] is closer

Comment: in the comment i have provide [16,16] as the new point for search. Sure will update question with this also.

Comment: When I run it with [16,16] I get [[15, 15, 8, 10], [6, 6, 8, 10], [3, 3, 8, 10]]

Comment: But I realize I forgot to take the absolute difference for the simple difference (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension to get distances (I'm using Euclidian distances here):

```
data = [[6,5,7,8],[2,5,5,6]]
query = [3,5]
distances = [pow(sample[0]-query[0],2)+pow(sample[1]-query[1],2) for sample in data]
# No need to calculate roots i.e actual distance as you just need to compare
```

Then you can sort the data by distances using:

```
sorted_data = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(distances, data))]
```

Doing this you get *sorted_data = [[2, 5, 5, 6], [6, 5, 7, 8]]*

Comment: like looks a lot like a more complicated and less efficient version of my answer :p

Comment: just using Euclidian instead of absolute distance :)

Comment: @gokaii read all my answer ;)

Comment: good point, of not computing the roots, I will update that

Comment: Well, to be fair, I don't see the point of your answer… the temporary list is also unnecessary, and the use or math.pow